# Send 2 level complex object in POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a 2 level complex object in my Angular Js form like

```
{
    "name":"",
    "email":"",
    "friends":[
        {
            "name":"",
            "email":""
        },
        {
            "name":"",
            "email":""
        }
   ]
}
```

I am able to send all the attributes to the server side, except the friends. If I check the chrome developer extension console for request, friends attribute is always getting passed as friends:`"[[]]"`

I have used JSON.stringify on the main object as well on friends, but hard luck.
I am using Angular Js as the Front end which is making a call to the Node js service.

Comment: How are you making the request? Can you post your code

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this question without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example of the expected and actual behavior.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Agreed; `JSON.stringify()` does correctly serialize that object, so we're going to need to see your code before we can identify where it's failing.

Comment: I tried creating array like var friends = []; var friend = {name: "", id=0}; friends.push(friend) and then I tried using to stringify it JSON.stringify(friends) for which it gives value as [[]]

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution to the problem. The issue was that I have defined the Array of objects wrongly. It should have been var friends={}; instead of var friends=[];